# The "Angular" way of testing a component

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, angular

In angular 1, if I wrote a component, I would make sure that:

- Dependencies, such as services is being mocked.
- Unit tests are written for methods within the component.
- **The component is calling the service to retrieve the data** `expect(service.method).toHaveBeenCalled()`
- The component is updating the view given an updated model.

I've been doing some research on Angular 2 component testing, and for all the articles I can find, it seems that testing is being done as follows;

- Create a service mock that returns a fixed result (ex: 'Test Quote')
- Expect that the view contains the result coming from the mocked service (ex; that there's a div somewhere that has `<div>Test Quote</div>`).

Here are a few examples of such articles (basically top results on google for 'Angular 2 Component Testing')

- http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/testing-angular-2-components-unit-tests-testcomponentbuilder/
- http://blog.rangle.io/testing-angular-2-applications/
- http://www.itsmycodeblog.com/angular2-unit-testing-a-component/
- https://developers.livechatinc.com/blog/testing-angular-2-apps-dependency-injection-and-components/

Since NG2 provides no spies in it's testing framework `@angular/core/testing`, it's recommended to avoid the step in bold altogether? Or should we be including jasmine to just have access to spies?

Answer (score 0):

if you are specifically looking to test component rendering, then you can use `TestComponentBuilder` as explained in blogs mentioned in your question.

```
    describe('MyComponent', () => {

      it('should render list', async(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
        return tcb.createAsync(MyComponent).then((componentFixture: ComponentFixture) => {
          const element = componentFixture.nativeElement;
         //... get the element you want to check 
          componentFixture.detectChanges();
          expect(element).toHaveText('test div');
          expect(element.querySelectorAll('div').length).toBe(1);
        });
      }));    
}));
```

if a service is being called in component then you want to `inject` in `beforeEachProviders()` or `beforeEach()` method  like :

```
beforeEach(() => {
    addProviders([
      provide(LoginService, { useClass: MockLoginService }),
      UserService
    ]);
  });
```

using `jasmine` spies  along with methods like `and.callThrough` and `and.returnValue` is very useful when you want to mock a service call in component. Additionally, have a look at [this](https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed) repo by angular team member julie raplh.